# MongoDB find most recent object in array and compare to known values

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

Assuming I have the below documents:

```
[
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("56478eaff7717496f23f1000"),
    "thresholds": {
      "notify": 70,
    },
    "scores": [
      {
        "date": ISODate("2021-05-17T04:00:00.443Z"),
        "total": 0.60
      },
      {
        "date": ISODate("2021-05-31T05:06:27.543Z"),
        "total": 0.71
      }
    ]
    },
     
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("56478eaff7717496f23f1001"),
    "thresholds": {
      "notify": 70,
    },
    "scores": [
      {
        "date": ISODate("2021-05-17T04:00:00.443Z"),
        "total": 0.52
      },
      {
        "date": ISODate("2021-05-31T05:06:27.543Z"),
        "total": 0.69
      }
    ]
    }
]
```

I want to find documents where an object(s) within the array of scores that has date past a certain timestamp and where the total has a value greater than thresholds.notify/100 (.70 in this case). Currently, I have:

```
db.collection.find({
  "scores": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "total": {
        $gte: {
          $divide: [
            "$thresholds.notify",
            100
          ]
        }
      },
      "date": {
        $gte: ISODate("2021-05-31T00:18:57.806Z")
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This search should return Object 56478eaff7717496f23f1000, but it returns 0 documents. I am not sure why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Pipeline:

- `$unwind` to deconstructs `scores` field
- `$addFields` to add new field `flag` and set it to 1 if the `total` has a value greater than `thresholds.notify/100`
- `$match` to match all document that has `flag` property equal to 1, and `scores.date` is after or equal to specified timestamp.
- `$group` to return all unique `_id` properties

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$scores"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "flag": {
        "$cmp": [
          "$scores.total",
          {
            "$divide": [
              "$thresholds.notify",
              100
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "flag": 1,
      "scores.date": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2021-05-31T00:18:57.806Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y-fEasiSsEg